# How to pass an array to a python class in FLASK

Tags: python, flask

I started working with flask-python recently.
I am trying to send an array read from the database to a class that defines a form.
Here is my class :

```
# livraison Form Class
class livraisonForm(Form):

    list_assurances=['-', u'Aucune assurance trouvée']

    type_assur = SelectField(u'Type d\'assurance', choices=list_assurances)


    # INIT function :
    def __init__(self, list_assurances, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Form)
        self.list_assurances = list_assurances
```

Here is how I am trying to pass the array to the init function

```
def add_livraison():
    form = livraisonForm(request.form, get_assurances())
```

the get_assurances() function returns an array as mentionned below :

```
def get_assurances():

    # Create db cursor
    cur = mysql.get_db().cursor()

    # Get user by username
    result = cur.execute("SELECT ID_ASSURANCE, DESCRIPTION FROM type_assurance ")

    if result > 0:
        # Get assurances list
        data = cur.fetchone()

        # Close connection
        cur.close()
        return [(i[0]+'',  i[1]+'') for i in data]


    # Close connection
    cur.close()

    return ['-', u'Aucun assur trouvée']
```

unfortunately, I am having this problem concerning the form class :

> TypeError: 'UnboundField' object is not callable

I tried to delete the list_assurances variable from the form and called the function directly but I got a problem saying that the database has no attribute cursor.

I would like to know what is the right way to send an array to a class -form class- in flask.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
   form = livraisonForm(request.form, get_assurances())
```

Here you're actually assigning the request.form to the self.assurances, not get_assurances() as you should.

Try it like that:

```
form = livraisonForm(get_assurances())
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried that but got this error "TypeError: 'UnboundField' object is not callable". Is it because I am using an array in the form class, I mean it isn't an input object! Thanks